Loop through all stages in schema within a stored procedure and pass them on as arguments
I am trying to tweak my stored procedure in Snowflake so that I can loop through all external stages (in S3) from my schema manual_adjustments and not have to call this other procedure CHECK_LOAD() multiple times as seen below. At the moment I have put together the following:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MANUAL_ADJUSTMENTS.TASK_FAILURE_ALERT()
RETURNS VARIANT
LANGUAGE SQL
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
$$
BEGIN
    CALL manual_adjustments.CHECK_LOAD('stage1');
    CALL manual_adjustments.CHECK_LOAD('stage2');
    CALL manual_adjustments.CHECK_LOAD('stage3');
    CALL manual_adjustments.CHECK_LOAD('stage4');
    CALL manual_adjustments.CHECK_LOAD('stage5');
    CALL manual_adjustments.CHECK_LOAD('stage6');
    CALL manual_adjustments.CHECK_LOAD('stage7');
    CALL manual_adjustments.CHECK_LOAD('stage8');
END;
$$;

The above is working ok, but is it possible to get a list of all stage names from my schema and loop through them, so I can pass them on as arguments to this other procedure CHECK_LOAD() ? I know the command "SHOW STAGES" could work, but not sure how to use this within a stored procedure nor how to loop through them?

After SHOW STAGES, use this to get the results and then you can process them: SELECT * FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()))

Thanks for this. Now how could I now loop through the results_scan table to add the stage names as arguments to that procedure?

By using a cursor and a FOR loop to loop through the contents of the cursor. There are examples in the documentation, and elsewhere, showing how to do this

Ok sure thanks for your help.

Here is a working answer using Javascript. It calls SHOW STAGES, loops through the results, and calls CHECK_LOAD for each stage.
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MANUAL_ADJUSTMENTS.TASK_FAILURE_ALERT()
RETURNS VARIANT
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
$$
var stages = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: "SHOW STAGES"}).execute();
var resultArray = [];
while (stages.next()) {
  var stageName = stages.getColumnValue("name");
  snowflake.createStatement({
    sqlText: "CALL CHECK_LOAD(?)",
    binds: [stageName]
  }).execute();
}
return {}
$$
;


Thanks for this. Can we pass the schema name as a parameter so it knows which stages to select from? Thank you

Another alternative using execute immediate from. The idea is to build a sql file, dump it into a temp stage and execute it from there, and clean up afterwards. I am using information_schema.stages view but you can also use result_scan of show stages in your_schema to build the dynamic sql. You can run just the SQL portion to see what query it built.
create or replace temporary stage query_stage;

copy into @query_stage/dynamic_sql.sql
from (select listagg(concat('call your_schema.your_sp',$$('$$,stage_name,$$')$$),';\n')
      from information_schema.stages
      where stage_schema='your_schema')
file_format = (compression = None, field_delimiter = None, record_delimiter = None)
overwrite = True
single = True; 

execute immediate from @query_stage/dynamic_sql.sql; --execute

remove @query_stage; --cleanup

